# No module named 'oauth2_provider.ext'

Tags: python, django, api

i'm having this error could someone help me with it.

File "/Users/king/Desktop/dash1-env/DASH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_social_oauth2/views.py", line 7, in 
from oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2_provider.ext'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same error.
Here is the solution:

```
pip install django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
```

instead of:

```
django-rest-framework-social-oauth2==1.0.4
```

...this version caused the error

Answer (score 0):

(I'm guessing outh2_provider.ext is a module)
The ModuleNotFoundError comes if you did not properly download the module, not download it at all, or mistyped it.

Go to the terminal inside of your script editor or IDE

to download with python 3 and above:

```
 pip3 install OAuth2 Provider
```

to download with python 2:

```
pip install OAuth2 Provider
```

It should download and the at the top instead of import oauth2_provider.ext you write:

```
import oauth2
```

Comment: it didn't work                                                                                                                      File "/Users/king/Desktop/dash1-env/DASH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_social_oauth2/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework import oauth2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2_provider.ext'

Comment: Could you be more precise, did the download not work or did the import command not work?